# Is #define local (in xcode)?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, include

Can I put `#define MY_VAR 1` in a file and `#define MY_VAR 2` in a different file without any problem?

In other words, is `#define` a local or a global definition?

Comment: I can't code right now :)

Comment: Do you plan to include one file from the other? Are you putting them in .h or .m files? It really all depends...

Comment: @Colas Why? are you in examination hall?

Comment: I am interested by both cases `.h` and `.m` but when none is included in the other.

Comment: Let's say I am using my iPhone ;)

Comment: @Colas see dasblinkenlight's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what kind of file you are talking about:

- If it is a header file, then your `#define`-d constant is visible in all files including the header
- If it is a .c/.m/.mm./.cpp file, then `#define`d constant is limited in scope to the file where it is defined.

Comment: Technically, the scope is limited to the *translation unit*, isn't it? - A .c file *can* be included from another .c/.m/... file.

Comment: @MartinR Correct the scope is the translation unit from the point of where `#define` first appears. My answer assumes that the OP is not doing anything unusual, such as using `#include` with .c files, etc.